@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView not working in input DTO (quarkus)
View class:
public class Views { 
    public static interface Public {
        
    }
    public static interface Private {
        
    }
}

And a dto:
public class Dto {
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String publicField;

    @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
    private String privateField;
}

Everything is perfectly working if the dto is used as response
@GET public Dto getData(){}
But it's not working if used as input parameter:
@POST public void getData(Dto dto){}
Is there a way to achieve this
